# Alamofire Not Working Properly - Tuple Issue Different number of elements

Tags: ios, xcode, tuples, alamofire

Using Xcode 7.1

In the Alamofire responseJSON request I cannot put 4 parameters. 
Below is the code

```
 let url2 = "https://httpbin.org/get"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON{ request, response, JSON, error  in
        print(JSON)
    }
```

I get this error: Tuple types '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result)' (aka '(Optional, Optional, Result)') and '(_, _, _, _)' have a different number of elements (3 vs. 4)

If I remove the "**error**" parameter from **responseJSON** and run it...the app builds but no json is printed on the console..

```
  let url2 = "https://httpbin.org/get"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON{ request, response, JSON in
        print(JSON)
    }
```

**Console Output**

[image]

There is no JSON being printed. If you go to sample [URL](https://httpbin.org/get) from the code you will see JSON.

I have followed the instructions from [GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) but its not working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alamofire v1.x had four parameters to the `responseJSON` closure. Alamofire v2.x had three parameters. Alamofire v3.x now calls the closure with a single parameter, a `Response`:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { response in
    switch (response.result) {
    case .Success(let value):
        print(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
        if let data = response.data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print(string)
        }
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `isSuccess`, `isFailure`, `value`, `data` and `error` computed properties for `Result`, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { response in
    print(response.result.value)
}
```

[This has been updated for the Alamofire 3 syntax. If you need the Alamofire 2 syntax, please refer to this question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32507421/revisions).]

Comment: @Rob now Alamofire in 3.0 only returns the error in case of  `.Failure` because the `response` struct. I think you need to remove the `let data` of your switch

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on Github has not been updated to the latest version of Alamofire.

To see the properties that Rob pointed out, check the source code of the Framework.