# Swift 2 Json Alamofire Error "..expects 1 argument, but 3 were specified" iOS 9 Xcode 7

Tags: json, xcode, ios9, alamofire

I've tried to implement JSON Parsing in my App to see the latest Wordpress Posts from my website.

Now i have the following error:

"Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, but 3 were specified"

The "Problem Code"

```
func getPosts(getposts : String)
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, getposts, parameters:parameters)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in

            switch result
            {
                case .Success(let data):

                    self.json = JSON(data)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me (:

Best regards!

Comment: I downloaded this one yesterday

https://github.com/alamofire/alamofire

I think its Version 3 ..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32506703/1271826

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, but 4 were specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384342/contextual-type-for-closure-argument-list-expects-1-argument-but-4-were-specifi)

Answer (score 3):

I Got it !

```
func getPosts(getposts : String)
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, getposts, parameters:parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard let data = response.result.value else{
                print("Request failed with error")
                return
            }

            self.json = JSON(data)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code which takes Base URL and Parameter to service and method type.

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.abc.cpm", parameters: ["consumer_key": "fnfkdkdndf"]).responseJSON { response in

           print(response)

        }
```